# How do you get various algorithm analysis factors in your code?

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I am attempting to prepare a presentation to explain the basics of algorithm analysis to my co-workers - some of them have never had a lecture on the subject before, but everyone has at least a few years programming behind them and good math backgrounds, so I think I can teach this.  I can explain the concepts fine, but I need concrete examples of some code structures or patterns that result in factors so I can demonstrate them.

Geometric factors (n, n^2, n^3, etc) are easy, embedded loops using the same sentinel, but I am getting lost on how to describe and show off some of the less common ones.

I would like to incorporate *exponential* (2^n or c^n), *logarithmic* (n log(n) or just log(n)) and *factoral* (n!) factors in the presentation.  What are some short, teachable ways to get these in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exponential: [naive Fibonacci implementation](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~sriram/80/spring2009/notes/exponentialRunningTime.html).

n log(n) or just log(n): [Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Binary seach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Factorial: Naive traveling salesman solutions. Many naive solutions to NP-complete problems.

Answer (score 3):

A divide-and-conquer algorithm that does a constant amount of work for each time it divides the problem in half is `O(log n)`. For example a binary search.

A divide-and-conquer algorithm that does a linear amount of work for each time it divides the problem in half is `O(n * log n)`. For example a merge sort.

Exponential and factorial are probably best illustrated by iterating respectively over all subsets of a set, or all permutations of a set.

Answer (score 2):

n! problems are pretty simple. There are many NP-complete n! time problems such as [the travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

Comment: For geeks: it's not proved that Travelling Salesman actually requires factorial time, because it's not proved whether P = NP. Certainly it can be done in not much more than factorial time :-)

Answer (score 0):

In doubt pick one of the Sort algorithms - everyone knows what they're supposed to do and therefore they're easy to explain in relation to the complexity stuff: [Wikipedia has a quite good overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)